# How to scroll a part of the page when the mouse is over other parts of the page?

Tags: javascript, scroll

Please have a look at [my sample page](http://www.applegrew.com/so_sample1/).

On that page notice the portion with the gibberish text. This is the "content part" which is meant to be scrolled. All other parts are supposed to be fixed.

If you move your mouse over the left navigation or the header and try to scroll, then naturally nothing happens.

How do I make the content part scroll even when the user's mouse is over the header or left navigation or any other fixed parts?

**PS.** I am trying to imitate Google Plus here. They seemed to have a `scroll` listener, but the Javascript code is too mangled for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong in my previous conclusion that Google+ is using Javascript for this.

Yesterday broke down their site into pieces using Firebug. Now it is clear that they too are using `position: fixed` for fixed parts.

[Here is my updated sample page.](http://www.applegrew.com/so_sample2/) Notice that now we can use keyboard arrows too to move the page up or down. This page is not using any Javascript.